# How to Programmatically Prefix an Image URL with PHP?

Tags: php, regex, url-rewriting, preg-replace, filenames

I'm working with PHP and a JSON-based API that returns 2 fields with values for property photos:

1. photo_url
2. has_large

The photo_url is the regular sized photo URL.

**Example:** https://secure.example.org/Directory/AnotherDirectory/0008/102/12.jpg

If has_large = true, then we know a large photo exists, but the API doesn't return the specific URL.

However, from the API documentation, we know that if we prefix the image filename with a  'L', this gives us the correct large image URL:

**Example:** https://secure.example.org/Directory/AnotherDirectory/0008/102/L12.jpg

How can I programmatically prefix the filenames with the letter L, before writing them to the database (MySQL)?

**Note:**  The URL structure is nearly the same for all photos.

The only parts of the image URLs that change for each property are:

1. The 4th level directory which specifies property ID *(In the example above -- 102)*
2. The filename itself, which is a maximum of 3 numbers *(In the URL example above -- 12.jpg)*.

After hours of research on RegEx, preg_replace() and looking for similar solutions on StackOverflow, I'm still not sure how to accomplish this correctly using PHP.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you only need to prepend a file name (without path) with `L`. A file name without path is anything but `/` in at the end of string, which in regex looks `([^\/]+)$`. Therefore the desired replacement function is:

```
$large_photo_url = preg_replace('/([^\/]+)$/', 'L$1', $photo_url);
```

Comment: Can you explain to me what the second parameter ($1) in the preg_replace is doing and how it represents the letter L?

Comment: @ju1985oh `$1` is the first capture group (everything from the last `/` until the end of the string).

Answer (score 1):

Here we are using `explode` function, to `split` a string on `/` and then appending `L` at the very end value of that array.

**Solution 1:**

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/798519)

```
<?php

$link="https://secure.example.org/Directory/AnotherDirectory/0008/102/12.jpg";
$portions=explode("/",$link);
$portions[count($portions)-1]="L".$portions[count($portions)-1];
print_r(implode("/", $portions));
```

**Solution 2:**

**Regex:** `([^\/]+)$`

> **1.** `([^\/]+)` match all till `/`(not including this), here circle `()` braces will capture the first captured result in `$1`,
>
> **2.** `$` end of string.

[**Regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/7cbNnD/2)

```
<?php

$link="https://secure.example.org/Directory/AnotherDirectory/0008/102/12.jpg";
echo preg_replace("/([^\/]+)$/", 'L$1', $link);
```

Answer (score 0):

For my case.. 
I am using this function to get the updated image url.

```
function thumb_url($image_url=''){

    $prefix = 'thumb';
    $photo_url = preg_replace('/([^\/]+)$/', "{$prefix}$1", $image_url); 

    return $photo_url;
}
```

credit goes to @Dmitry. I Just used his code to here.